# Неправильный перенос строки

Tags: html, css

проблема такая, сделал блок событий, строка переносится под картинку, а мне нужно чтобы переносилась под начало ссылки, прошу вашей помощи в решении.

[image: проблема]

Код блока:

```css
.title__block-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #272727;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 774px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.title__block-center h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}

.content_events {
  width: 774px;
  height: 600px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #484848;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.img__events {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.time__events {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #767676;
}

.content_events-link {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}

.content_events-link:hover {
  color: #949494;
}

.hr_block-content {
  width: 734px;
  margin: 20px auto 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent);
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="title__block-center">
    <h3>События</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content_events">
    <img class="img__events" src="img/events/events-1.jpg" alt="">
    <time class="time__events" datetime="2022-04-11">11.04.2022</time>
    <a class="content_events-link" href="#">Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев</a>
    <hr class="hr_block-content">
    <img class="img__events" src="img/events/events-2.jpg" alt="">
    <time class="time__events" datetime="2022-04-04">04.04.2022</time>
    <a class="content_events-link" href="#">2022 - Год культурного наследия народов России</a>
    <hr class="hr_block-content">
    <img class="img__events" src="img/events/events-3.jpg" alt="">
    <time class="time__events" datetime="2022-03-22">22.03.2022</time>
    <a class="content_events-link" href="#">Всероссийский конкурс лучших проектов создания комфортной городской среды</a>
    <hr class="hr_block-content">
    <img class="img__events" src="img/events/events-4.jpg" alt="">
    <time class="time__events" datetime="2022-03-03">03.03.2022</time>
    <a class="content_events-link" href="#">Формирование комфортной городской среды</a>
    <hr class="hr_block-content">
    <img class="img__events" src="img/events/events-5.jpg" alt="">
    <time class="time__events" datetime="2022-06-02">02.06.2021</time>
    <a class="content_events-link" href="#">Военная история России в событиях</a>
    <hr class="hr_block-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вам немного нужно переделать верстку на такой вариант

```css
.title__block-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #272727;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.title__block-center h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}

.content_events {
  height: 600px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #484848;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.img__events {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.time__events {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #767676;
}

.content_events-link {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}

.content_events-link:hover {
  color: #949494;
}

.hr_block-content {
  width: 734px;
  margin: 20px auto 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent);
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: block;
}
.wrapp {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.wrapp__news {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="title__block-center">
    <h3>События</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content_events">
    <div class="wrapp">
        <div class="wrapp__img">
            <img class="img__events" src="img/events/events-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="wrapp__news">
            <time class="time__events" datetime="2022-04-11">11.04.2022</time>
             <a class="content_events-link" href="#">Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr_block-content">

    <div class="wrapp">
        <div class="wrapp__img">
            <img class="img__events" src="img/events/events-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="wrapp__news">
            <time class="time__events" datetime="2022-04-11">11.04.2022</time>
             <a class="content_events-link" href="#">Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr_block-content">

    <div class="wrapp">
        <div class="wrapp__img">
            <img class="img__events" src="img/events/events-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="wrapp__news">
            <time class="time__events" datetime="2022-04-11">11.04.2022</time>
             <a class="content_events-link" href="#">Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев Сбор гуманитарной помощи для прибывших беженцев </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr_block-content">
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```